# Query opitimization in MongoDB using Java

Tags: java, performance, mongodb, mongodb-query

At first let me introduce my use case - I have a `collection` with documents where I store my XML `request`s and corresponding `response`s. Also each document has plenty of accompanying properties and some of them are indexed, but request and response aren't.

Whenever I search using indexed field the performance is sufficient. But there are situations where I have to prepare search using a regular expression basing on the request or response value.

For now I do something like this:

```
db.traffic.find(
    { $or: 
        [ { request: { $regex: "some.* code=\"123\"} },
          { response: { $regex: "some.* code=\"123\"} }] })
```

and I translated this into Java code. But querying is to slow and it takes significant amount of time comparing to other queries.

I can see two solutions:

1. indexing `request`s and `response`s - but I suppose that this is not a good idea as they are really long and most probably index will be huge.
2. querying using some `indexed` field first and then applying already mentioned query but in the descending order of found records and picking the very first found so I would like to do something like

   ```
   db.traffic.find({"conversationID": { $regex: "vendorName" }}).sort({"counter": -1}) 
       .findOne(
           { $or: 
               [ { request: { $regex: "some.* code=\"123\"} },
                 { response: { $regex: "some.* code=\"123\"} }] })
   ```

**So wrapping up - my question is:** should I choose the simpler solution which is indexing `request`s and `response`s? And what impact will it have on the size of my index?

Or should I choose the second way? But is my code correct and does it what I want?

Comment: Whatever anyone says, the best answer will always be to try both and benchmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I tried the second solution but I had slightly change it because of the fact that I can't run `findOne` on the query result. But I found the equivalent syntax.

So it looks now sth like this:

```
db.traffic.findOne($query: { $or: 
                            [ { request: { $regex: "some.* code=\"123\"} },
                              { response: { $regex: "some.* code=\"123\"} }] },
                   $orderby: { "counter": -1})
```

and the performance is much better now.

Also I used `explain` to check the real "speed".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried an explain on both methods?

Use the mongo shell to test queries, and add explain before the query, so:

```
db.traffic.explain()...
```

try both and you should get some information that indicates the direction.